# Modified volume size on the EBS volume doesn’t reflect it’s new size, it still shows up original size

Tags: mysql, operating-systems, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos-7

I have currently modified AWS EBS volume (volume type is gp2). The original size of disk is 50G,I have increased to 100G. The system is CentOS 7

That disk has MySQL server installed and has `ibdata` files and the EBS volume does not have any partitions.

After modifying the disk size, `lsblk` shows the correct size:

```
xvdf    202:80   0  100G  0 disk /var
```

But `df -h` still shows originial size:

```
/dev/xvdf        50G  9.9G   37G  22% /var
```

Is there anything else I should run? I tried to reboot the EC2 instance but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to run `sudo resize2fs -p /dev/xvdf` to grow the filesystem to fit the expanded size of the volume.  As with any such operation, it should be quite safe, but don't try it without a backup.

(`-p` is for a progress bar)

Comment: My disk does not have partition, is this command still applicable then ? This wont create any corrupt blocks right?

Comment: The fact that this disk doesn't have a partition table is why you can resize the filesystem so easily with resize2fs.  It will grow to the size of the volume.  If you had a partition table, you'd need to modify that, first, and use the partition number in the command, e.g. `/dev/xvdf1` for the first partition.